# How can I pass 'hello' to render a dynamic html page like the 'user' variable? My cb is broken now. Very new to this

Tags: json, node.js, express, nosql, ibm-cloud

```
app.get('/indexInstHome.html', 
    require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn('indexErrorAccount.html'), 
    function(req, res, cb)
         {
         test.find({selector:{"Class.email": req.user._id }}, function(er, 
         result, cb) {
                     if (er) {
                         console.log(er);
                     }
                     hello = result.docs;
                     return cb(hello);
             });
    hello = cb();
    console.log(hello);
    res.render('indexInstHome.html', { user: req.user, Classes: hello });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `test.find` does but I'm assuming it's some sort of asynchronous DB query. I don't know what the third argument (the callback) would be used for but I don't think it's needed for what you're trying to do.

I suggest using the name `next` for the Express callback as that convention is pretty much universal, you'll only confuse other people if you start calling it `cb`.

The main problem with your code seems to be a misunderstanding about how callbacks work with asynchronous code. It's much simpler than you're trying to make it, you just need to wait for the asynchronous process to finish before you try to render your page. You do that by putting the relevant code inside the callback function, i.e. the `function` that you pass to `find`.

I've had to make a few assumptions about what you're trying to do but I think it'd be something like this:

```
app.get('/indexInstHome.html', 
    require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn('indexErrorAccount.html'), 
    function(req, res, next) {
        test.find({selector: {"Class.email": req.user._id}}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                next(err);
            }
            else {
                // Assuming result cannot be null
                var hello = result.docs;

                console.log(hello);
                res.render('indexInstHome.html', { user: req.user, Classes: hello });
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try it in a couple of hours when I get home. Your assumption is correct about text.find. I thought that cb meant callback not next, I though they were two different functions . However, I will call it next from here on out. Yes, I don't understand how callbacks work. If you have any suggestions on any learning resources I would like to hear them too. Thanks again.

Comment: Your original code had two things called `cb`, so to be clear it's the one in `function(req, res, cb)` that should be called `next`, i.e. `function(req, res, next)`. You also created two anonymous functions which could potentially be described as 'callbacks', making it difficult to use the term without ambiguity.